# to what does ''where'' refer?

Tags: relative-clauses

It is a sentence from the book ''Travel in Southeast Asia".

> If one has a taste for mountains and hills, one can take
>   a trip to the Shan hills where the weather is cooler.

In this sentence, what does ''where'' refer to?

1. in the Shan hills
2. the Shan hills
3. on the Shan hills

I learn that 'where' is a relative pronoun.
It means 'in which' or 'on which'.
As the former place is the Shan hills, I think the answer is ''in the Shan hills''.

Comment: What do you think is the answer? Show us the research you have done, please.

Comment: I found 'where' means ''in which/on which.''So I think 'where' refers to 'in Shan hills''.

Comment: When your question is edited for clarity, you should leave it as edited. In its original fornat, it is difficult to read and includes punctuation errors. Also, the word "where" is not a "relative clause." Can you tell us where you learned that?

Comment: @Alarn Carmack Can you explain it to me more? why you think 'where' refers to 'noun phrase' than 'a true location in this OP.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I've edited my post.What about your  answer for this question?

Comment: AlanCarmack's answer is accurate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45081/discussion-between-learner-and-p-e-dant).

Answer (score 2):

> If one has a taste for mountains and hills, one can take a trip to the Shan hills **where** the weather is cooler.

*Where* is a relative pronoun. It can be used instead of *in which* and *on which* when talking about a location. It refers  back to the nearest noun phrase, which is *the Shan hills*, which I might write as *the Shan Hills*.  It does not refer to *in the Shan hills* because that phrase is not used in the sentence.

*Where* can also be used to stand for a noun phrase that is not a true location, for example to a *situation*, but this  is beyond the scope of this question. I have mentioned this  for completeness.